# Is there any way that i can put my nib files in the framework

Tags: iphone, ios, frameworks

I was doing a framework for ios and I was successful in adding the .h and .m files and accessing them from the constructed framework. But if I add any xib files to the framework it cant be accessed in the projects which imports my framework. any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution i was trying to access the nib from main bundle. I was supposed to access from the frameworks bundle.